# Matlab parfor and vectorization for assigning in the same matrix

Tags: matlab, vectorization, parfor

i have a two questions regarding the same sample MATLAB code:

```
for i = 1:N
 for j = 1:4
  M(CONNECT(e(i),j)) = M(CONNECT(e(i),j))+p(i)*N(i,j);  
 end
end
```

1. Why cant i use parfor straight away for the first for(i) since each i works on a single entry of M independently?
2. Can this simple code be vectorized since the M matrix is used in both parts of the assign(=)?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Looks like `M(CONNECT(e(1:N),1:4)) = M(CONNECT(e(1:N),1:4))+p(1:N)*N(1:N,1:4);`

Comment: @Yvon you probably need a `.*` (element-wise multiplication) instead of just `*`

Answer (score 0):

`parfor` places restrictions on the form of indexing you're allowed to use for output variables. Even though you might well be operating on the elements of `M` independently, the `parfor` infrastructure needs to be able to prove that's what's happening ahead of time. So, the restriction for a sliced output variable is basically that you must use the loop variable `i` directly in the index list for `M`. More details in the doc [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/classification-of-variables-in-parfor-loops.html).

I am going to presume that `CONNECT` is either another variable, or a simple function - in which case, it seems highly likely that your best bet is to pursue vectorisation. Whether this code can be vectorised depends on details you haven't shown us - i.e. we need a minimal working example. `parfor` is usually only beneficial when the amount of computation in the body of the loop is large compared to the amount of data that must be transferred to run the loop.

Comment: Edric, thank you for your time and answer,
e(i) is a vector tha holds integers (in which "box" a body resides for example)
CONNECT(i,j) is a matrix that holds the numbers of the four nodes of i th box
M is a matrix that holds the properties for the nodes
which is updated by projecting and adding the body property p multiplied by a shape function N to the 4 nodes of the box it resides.